# How can I delete/remove a VB macro?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, vba

I have created a VB macro in Outlook 2007 and I no longer need it. I want to remove it from Outlook. How can I do this?

To create a macro you just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and up pops the editor. You enter code and once I restart Outlook it's now enabled. I cannot work out how to undo this. Even if I delete the actual code from the editor the macro is still there and I get macro warnings from it.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to delete it from the Macro Window (Alt+F8)? Also, when you deleted it from VBA editor did you click the save icon? Any additional code in a `Module` or in `ThisSession`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just rename or move the applicable [VBA or Macros files](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1424) as detailed in the article.

For Outlook 2007 on Vista/7/8:

```
Macros and VBA programs (VbaProject.otm):
drive:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook
```

where `drive` is e.g. `C`

If you don't care about ANY of the data contained within the VbaProject.otm file, then delete the file. Otherwise just move it into another place that isn't that directory and it should stop telling you you have macros.